# Programmatically add breadcrumbs paths in Magento?

Tags: magento

In Magento, when the user directly accesses the product page, such as from Google, the breadcrumbs would only be "Home" -> "Product Name".

[How can I add categories in there even when users access the page directly from Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417499/making-consistent-breadcrumbs-on-individual-product-pages-in-magento)

For example, on [this page](http://www.princessly.com/sexy-short-sheath-blooms-one-shoulder-backless-natural-waist-ruched-satin-bridal-dress.html), I want to add the categories "Wedding Apparel" and "Wedding Dresses" in the breadcrumbs. I came up with an idea other than hard editing breadcrumbs.phtml but is there any way I can programmatically add a breadcrumbs item in template/catalog/product/view.phtml ?

I can get the categories (title and link) of the current product and then use some function / method to add them in the breadcrumbs dynamically and programmatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code that forces Magento to display the complete breadcrumb, including categories by looping trough each category for the current product:

© Danny Vince

```
<?php
if ($product = Mage::registry('current_product')) {
    $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection()->load();

    if($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            if($category) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    $lastCrumbName = $product->getName();
    $lastCategoryAdjust = 0;
}
else {
    if($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
    $lastCrumbName = $category->getName();
    }
    $lastCategoryAdjust = 1;
}

if($category) {
    if($path = $category->getPath()) {
        $path = explode('/', $path);
        $crumbs = array('home' => array('label' => 'Home',
        'title' => 'Home',
        'link' => Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB),
        'first' => true,
        'last' => false
        ));
        for($i = 2; $i < count($path) - $lastCategoryAdjust; $i++) {
            $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($path[$i]);
            if($cur_category && $cur_category->getIsActive()) {
                $crumbs['category' . $path[$i]] = array('label' => $cur_category->getName(),
                'title' => $cur_category->getName(),
                'link' => $cur_category->getUrl(),
                'first' => false,
                'last' => false
                );
            }
        }
        $crumbs['current'] = array('label' => $lastCrumbName,
        'title' => '',
        'link' => '',
        'first' => false,
        'last' => true
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jace, so where should I put this snippet? breadcrumbs.phtml? view.phtml?

Comment: This code should be added to the top of your breadcrumbs.phtml file located in: app/design/frontend/default/template_name/template/page/html/

Comment: I suppose this would add to the page load time because it unnecessarily loops through the entire category path, I can live a slight increase in page load time if this does what I needed, but can you please give me an idea of how much? How much more server burden and load time this would cause to my website? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That really depends on how many categories you have but as far as I know you shouldn't worry in case you have < 50 categories since the load time would increase by 1-2 seconds in worst case scenario. Unfortunately it has to loop trough teh category path to provide linked categories to your breadcrumbs.

Comment: Thank you, Jace, it works. The page load time is increased by about 0.05 second according to microtime().

Comment: I'm trying this solution on Magento 1.7 and i can't retrieve Categories nor Breadcrumbs. It retrieves only first product category but not parent ones. When it builds the breadcrumbs these are Home->Product just as default.

Comment: Make sure that you are adding the following code to the breadcrumbs.phtml file of your current theme, otherwise you will not see any changes. This solution has been tested and works properly in Magento 1.7 as well