# How to change the Magento home page product breadcrumbs path

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

I am using dresscode template of magento.It has a module to display products in home page like carousel.If i have click on the product image means the page which redirects shows the breadcrumb as Home -> product name.

I need to change this breadcrumb path to Home -> category  -> product name.

How to get this?

My function used to get the breadcrumb path

```
 public function getBreadcrumbPath()
    {
        if (!$this->_categoryPath) {

            $path = array();
            if ($category = $this->getCategory()) {
                $pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
                $pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));

                $categories = $category->getParentCategories();

                // add category path breadcrumb
                foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                    if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && $categories[$categoryId]->getName()) {
                        $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
                            'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
                            'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($this->getProduct()) {
if($this->getProduct()->getproduct_title()!='')
{

$path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getproduct_title());
}
else
{
$path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());

}
            }

            $this->_categoryPath = $path;
        }
        return $this->_categoryPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check following url to acheive above thing.

http://dltr.org/blog/magento/381/Magento-Force-Display-Full-Breadcrumb-Path

Also

[Programmatically add breadcrumbs paths in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576614/programmatically-add-breadcrumbs-paths-in-magento)

Comment: Hi i have tried with both links but its not supporting for me.

Comment: may be you need to point out the code that is needed by you from the links above and use it in the right file or block.

Comment: Hi i have updated my post with the function which i have used to get the breadcrumb path can u please point out in which place i have to append the code

Comment: what is the current output on your site ?

Comment: If i have implemented this link i have got the home ->product name alone at first now i have deselect the root category for the products displaying in home page.its working fine now according to my requirement.home -> category -> product name.Thank u..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42937/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-skv)