# How to get full breadcrumb in product listing page [Magento]

Tags: magento

As i browse through categories and subcategories
[image]

i can see the full breadcrumb. `[Home > Electronics > Smartphone]`

But as i enter the product listing page (After i selected apple)

[image]

i can't see that full breadcrumb. It only shows parent categories. `[Home > Electronics]`

**Problem** : how to get full categories and subcategories breadcrumb in my case `[Home > Electronics > Smartphone > Apple]`

Comment: Is this any use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417499/making-consistent-breadcrumbs-on-individual-product-pages-in-magento

Comment: @McNab i'm in product listing page. not in product detail page. :(

Comment: Sorry!  Not reading properly, need more coffee. How's about this then http://dltr.org/blog/magento/381/Magento-Force-Display-Full-Breadcrumb-Path